# Как получить массив строк из файла

Tags: java

Как получить массив строк из файла?
Например в файле были такие данные:

1. Петя;
2. Cаня;
3. Катя;

Answer (score 2):

Способов куча, например так:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(<ваш путь до файла>);
    List<String> read = Files.readAllLines(path);
    for (String s : read) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А вообще легко гуглиться ))

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] text = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new File("путь до файла");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            int i = 0;
            
            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                i++;
                text[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            }
        
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Если вы не хотите использовать ArrayList, то этот способ для вас.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            File file = new File("путь до файла");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                    
            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                text.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

этот способ более правильный т.к. он использует ArrayList.